# No drift brownian motion problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Given two same brownian motion with no drift and different variances:

$$dG_1= \sigma_1 G_1 dW $$
$$dG_2= \sigma_2 G_2 dW $$

and two barriers $P_1 > P_2$
[image]

assuming that $ \sigma_1 > \sigma_2 $
and given $τ_1=\inf [t:G_1(t)≥P_1] $; $τ_2= \inf [t:G_2(t)≥P_2]$

is it possible to find $P(τ_1<τ_2)$?

(the probability that a certain time $\tau\ $ "G1 will hit the barrier P1 earlier than G2 hits P2"?)

Comment: Can you clarify your last sentence? I don't understand the role of $\tau$.  And when you say "hit the barrier faster" do you just mean "earlier"?

Comment: Yes, earlier is better. For $ \tau $ that's just to identify the value of time at which G1 hit the barrier P1

Comment: Ok, so if we let $\tau_1 = \inf\{t : G_1(t) \ge P_1\}$ and $\tau_2 = \inf\{t : G_2(t) \ge P_2\}$, your question is "What is $\mathbb{P}(\tau_1 < \tau_2)$?"  Is that right?

Comment: I'm also confused by your definition of the processes $G_1, G_2$.  Is $G_1$ supposed to satisfy the SDE $dG_1 = \sigma_1 G_1 dW$ for $W$ a Brownian motion?  If so, then $G_1$ is not itself a Brownian motion.  Why does $W$ have a subscript $g$?  And are both processes $G_1, G_2$ supposed to be driven by the same Brownian motion $W$?

Comment: Yes they are. Thanks for the pointers I'll edit the question.